# How to add oracle data source in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, datasource, sql-server-2012-express, reportmanager

I've installed SQL Server 2012, after I've installed all features including report services. I go to Report Manager link and wanted to add New Data Source, but in Data Source Types there is only Microsoft SQL Server and I want to add Oracle Data Source.

Other way I easily connected to Oracle Data Source in Business Inteligence Studio, but I can't deploy Report file (`.rdl`) to my report manager because it gives me an error message:

> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server 2012 are you using?

Comment: sql server 2012 exress advanced edition , version 11.0.2100.60

Comment: Have you installed the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle?

Comment: i don't know sure, but is it possible to check if it's already installed? i looked in assemblies an there is assembly named OracleDataAcess

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle provider on both your dev computer and the server?

Comment: Yes It's Installed on both systems.

Comment: See my edit, you can't connect to Oracle with an Express Edition. The documentation is confusing though, because if you follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), you see that SSRS 2005 Express doesn't support Oracle Data Source and switching to SSRS 2008 R2 Express doesn't mention it, you have to go to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find out that it's not supported in SSRS 2008 R2 Express...

Comment: Yes I understand thank you a lot, than which version of sql server i must install?

Comment: Not the express one, so the Standard at least. If you can afford an Enterprise, it's up to you :) (If you want to use Data-Driven subscriptions, then choose at least the BI edition)

Comment: will it work on standart edition? is it free? or maybe Evaluation how you think?

Comment: You will be able to target Oracle with a Standard Edition. It is not free, unless you are using it for academic purposes, but this is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

You should install the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle on the server hosting the SSRS instance to be able to target an Oracle database.
[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html) is a link to download the latest version on [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html).

> **Remarks**
>   Before you can connect an Oracle data source, the system administrator must have installed the version of the .NET Data
>   Provider for Oracle that supports retrieving data from the Oracle
>   database. This data provider must be installed on the same computer as
>   Report Builder and also on the report server.

Source: [Oracle Connection Type (SSRS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220591%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Useful resources:

- [Using the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [How to use Reporting Services to configure and to access an Oracle data source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834305)

---

If you are using the **Express edition** of SQL Server, then Oracle Data Sources are not supported:

> Analysis Services, Oracle, XML, SAP, SQL Server Integration Services
>   (SSIS), OLE DB, and ODBC data sources are not supported.

Source: [Features Supported by Reporting Services in SQL Server Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

It applies to SSRS 2012 Express as well, as stated in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df5bfd8f-2a19-4c02-bab6-d1f53ea1d241/cannot-create-oracle-data-source-on-report-manager-mssql-2012-express-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices).